# Angular table how to put td based on th?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I would like to put some data in a table so that each data is correctly aligned with the corresponding `<th>` i am using [ng-zorro table](https://ng.ant.design/components/table/en) but i think it does not matter since it uses standard html tags.

I have this data that i gather from the server (c# web api) which is like this:

```
[
   {
      "code":"0001",
      "commissionId":"something",
      "commissionType":0,
      "description":"Some Description",
      "registrationList":[
         {
            "activityCode":"01.6",
            "activityDescription":"Desc1",
            "activityId":"ActivityId1",
            "minuteWorked":120
         }
         // ...
         // could have other data same as above
      ]
   }
   // ...
   // other data same as above
]
```

On the first array i can have multiple `commission`, and each commission have multiple elements inside the `registrationList`.
So that would be an array with multiple elements and each single element having another array (registrationList).

So what i need is to:

- display on the first column the commission code. The column is fixed. (that i know how to do)
- display the registration list on the table data. Matching the activityCode that is in the table header (this i do not know how to do)

**Here's the table**
[image: Here's the table]

---

What i have done is using `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` to loop through the first array and then loop on the `registrationList` but that does not work.

The `<th>` is generated looping through an `activityList`
So i did this in my code:

```html
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Commission</th>
    <th *ngFor="let activity of activityList" class="text-center">{{activity.code}}</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of serverData index as i">
    <td nzLeft>{{data?.code}} - {{data?.description}}</td>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let activity of activityList">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let r of serverData.registrationList">
        <td *ngIf="r.activityCode == activity?.code; else noData">{{data.description}} - {{r.activityCode}}
          <td #noData> no data </td>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

If anyone can guide me through a possible solution here, because somehow the table columns (the data) do not corresponds to the table heads and then the table layout is not correct. Thanks!

Comment: you wrote: <ng-container *ngFor="let r of serverData.registrationList">, it is not `<ng-container *ngFor="let r of data.registrationList">` (see "data" not "serverData")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the answer, your problem is not the frontend side. From what i can see you have to already format the data so that the front end will only display it. Let me explain:

- Usually if you have a backend it's best practice to leave high demanding task to backend. The front end part (Angular) is only there to display things, sure it can do more but doing an `*ngFor` like you did is not reasonable.

---

You can format the data in the backend server like this:

- create a class that holds the cells
- create a class that holds a row (wich is a list of cells)
- finally create a class that holds the entire table (with a thead with one row, and a tbody with a list of rows)

**PivotCelViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class PivotCelViewModel
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
```

**PivotRowViewModel.cs**

```
public class PivotRowViewModel
    {
        public PivotRowViewModel()
        {
            CellList= new List<PivotCelViewModel>();
        }

        public List<PivotCelViewModel>  CellList { get; set; }
    }
```

**PivotViewModel.cs**

```cs
 public class PivotViewModel
    {
        public PivotViewModel()
        {
            TBody = new List<PivotRowViewModel>();
        }
        public PivotRowViewModel THead { get; set; }
        public List<PivotRowViewModel> TBody { get; set; }
    }
```

In `PivotRowViewModel.cs` i am creating a constructor so that i can instantiate a new list every time. This ensure there is no errors when instantiating a new object of that class.

Then what you would probably do is populate those classes so that in front end you just have to `*ngFor` over the data withouth the need of specific logic.

Hope that helps cheers!